# Uploading a widget through Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento

I have developed a widget and now I want the clients to install it using Magento Connect Manager. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Magento connect is used to download and install *free*, *community* modules. If your module fits the bill, please continue.

First, you need to make sure that your widget is setup as an extension. That means that your code should be in a folder in `app/code/local` (though template files and such will clearly be in other places).

Once you've done that, [take a look here](http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/07/packaging-a-magento-extension/) for some detailed instructions on how to package your extension. Basically, you're going to select all the files that go with that extension and bundle them into a big blob.

Then, on the Magento website, you'll upload that file bundle to be placed on Magento Connect, where your clients can download and install it like any other community module.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: If this is the right answer to your question, you may want to click the checkmark arrow next to the answer to mark it as correct. You're more likely to get responses to your questions if you accept answers.

Comment: The only other thing I'd add is you can find the extension management page on the Magento site under "My Account", and then way down the left side.